# Why clearInterval doesn't work in my script for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have code for discord bot written in javascript for node.js. This code makes role to change colors like a rainbow.

```
function colorchanger (){
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length - 1; i++){
    myRole.setColor(colorArray[i]);
    console.log(`iteration`);
  }
}

if (cmd === `start`){
  console.log(`rainbow`);
  interval = setInterval(colorchanger, 10000);
}
else if (cmd === `stop`) {
  // stop execution of the interval previously created by setInterval
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log(`stoped`);
}
```

When I write in discord command "start" all works fine and role starts changing colors, and in the console, I have the message "rainbow".
But after I write stop, I see in console "stopped", but I still have iteration in console appear every 10 seconds and role keep changing colors.
Why clearInterval doesn't work?

Comment: Is your intervalId a global variable?

Comment: where/how is `interval` declared? I'm guessing with each command you send, `instance` is not the same variable

Comment: Been mentioned already, but you dont have the same instance of interval. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp